# OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: c#, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

Using the Facebook C# SDK, I'm getting the following error when I try to post a status update: 
 OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I am getting this error only with some users. For some other,status is updating fine. App is successfully getting access for all users.

This is the full code :

```
public partial class Authorize : Form
    {
        public Authorize()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public string ApplicationId 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"]; 
            } 
        }

        public string ExtendedPermissions 
        { 
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExtendedPermissions"];
            } 
        }

        public string AppSecret
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationSecret"];
            }
        }

        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        private void LoadAuthorize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var destinationURL = String.Format(
                @"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token",
                this.ApplicationId,
                this.ExtendedPermissions);
            webBrowser.Navigated += WebBrowserNavigated;
            webBrowser.Navigate(destinationURL);
        }

        private void WebBrowserNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get token
            var url = e.Url.Fragment;
            if (url.Contains("access_token") && url.Contains("#"))
            {
                this.Hide();
                url = (new Regex("#")).Replace(url, "?", 1);
                this.AccessToken = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url).Get("access_token");
                //MessageBox.Show(facebookCore.AccessToken);
                try
                {
                    //var facebooking = new FacebookingTest(facebookCore.AccessToken);
                    //facebooking.UpdateStatus();
                    var fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);
                    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = "Hi..Test33" });
                    var newPostId = result.id;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.Write(exception);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried the code given by Prabhir at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx ..same issue

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the access token has the 'publish_stream' or 'publish_actions' permission? the former is an optional permission that users can reject and/or revoke

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the file App.Config and modify the last line of the

```
<appsettings>
```

section as follows:

```
<add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access,publish_stream,publish_actions" />
```

Comment: Open the App.Config and modify the last line of the <appsettings> section as follows:

<add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access,publish_stream,publish_actions" />